# How to force typescript watcher to compile all .ts files without typing into those files?

Tags: typescript

I'm using Typescript watcher to compile .ts file in Pycharm. It works well every time I edit the .ts files. 
But when I clone the project from GitHub on a new machine, the project contains only .ts files and I need to type in a space in each .ts files and save to tell typescript watcher to compile. This is extremely annoying when I have tons of .ts files.

Is there any way to force typescript watcher to compile all .ts files without making changes to the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation of Typescript Watcher, you can compile all the files using the following command:

```
tscwatch build <rootPath> <outputPath> [options]
```

You can [read the documentation](https://github.com/damassi/TypeScript-Watcher) for the configuration options and for more details.

By the way, you should take note that TypeScript Watcher isn't being maintained anymore. I would suggest using something like basarat's [grunt-ts](https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts) as it is in active development.

Answer (score 0):

The **TypeScript** watcher has some limitations. *There is no way to natively add a watcher to a folder or directory.* So every time you add a new file or repo to your project you need to re execute the watcher command. Maybe [in a near future](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4222) an option will be available.

To achieve your requirement to compile all .ts files you can use one of the different build options described in the official TypeScript wiki. My favorite tool is the implementation made with Gulp by Ivo Gabe de Wolff [ivogabe/gulp-typescript](https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript).